# Aptana Studio browser preview problem - could not create the view

Tags: ide, aptana

Running Aptana Studio 3 on Mac osx 10.5.8 g4 powerbook I get the following error when I try to open the browser preview window to show my html.

"Could not create the view: An unexpected exception was thrown."

When I click the "show details" button, I get a whole bunch of

"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.PlatformOSHelper
    at com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.OSHelper.(OSHelper.java:30)
    at com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.CEFHelper.(CEFHelper.java:27)
...etc"

How can I make the in app browser preview window work?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written by Max Stepanov

At https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2423-aptana-studio-browser-preview-problem-could-not-create-the-view

> The current browser we use for
>   previewing is Chrome based. And
>   unfortunately there is no support for
>   PowerPC yet. We will apply a
>   workaround for PPC users in the Studio
>   3 final release to default to Safari
>   browser. The lighthouse ticket is
>   assigned for tracking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been addressed and fixed in Aptana Studio 3.0.0 final release.